# Filter files read using readdirp

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using this [readdirp npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/readdirp) to read files inside nested directories.

And it has option to filter files also.

By using that i added the file filter

```
readdirp('.', {fileFilter: '!image001.png', alwaysStat: true}) 
 .on('data', (entry) => { const {path, stats: {size}} = entry; 
  console.log(${JSON.stringify({path, size})}); 
})
```

my case is, if that file image001.png present two or more different nested directories means and i had to skip that file from only one location means , how to specify that particular file from particular location ????

i tried like this below code but not works, i think readdirp internally compares with file name only not path using picomatch.

```
readdirp('.', {fileFilter: '!D:fileuploader\NEW_TEST\image001.png', 
  alwaysStat: true}) .on('data', (entry) => { 
    const {path, stats: {size}} = entry; 
      console.log(`${JSON.stringify({path, size})}`); 
 })
```

Is there any way to do it ???

NOTE : I asked this in their github page also, i am asking here, because someone might faced this problem and may possibly fixed also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you shared what I understand is you need to skip only one file from the current directory. In this case you can put one condition to skip that file instead of filtering it. Please check the following code.

```
readdirp('.', { alwaysStat: true}).on('data', (entry) => {
    const {path, stats: {size}} = entry;
    if(path!="image001.png")
       console.log(JSON.stringify({path, size}));
});
```